# Cocoon Gem not displaying form - rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am unsure why my cocoon nested form is not appearing and any help would be much appreciated

- the `<button><%= link_to_add_association 'add a required skill', f, :requiredskills %></button>` works perfectly well in displaying a form
- but i am unsure why this is not rendering the form `<%= render 'requiredskill_fields', :f => duty %>`

> - what i would like to do is to have a form already displayed and when a user clicks `add a required skill`  another form is displayed.
>     At present when a user clicks `add a required skill` that displays
>     another form - the main issue is having a form to be displayed
>     initially. I am assuming this `<%= render 'requiredskill_fields', :f
>     => duty %>` is suppose to put a form in place but i am unsure why it is not working

user/_form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :firstname %>
    <%= f.input :lastname %>

    <h3>required skills & expertise</h3>
    <div>
      <div class="requiredskill_info" id="skill">
        <%= f.simple_fields_for :requiredskills do |skill| %>
          <%= render 'requiredskill_fields', :f => skill %>
        <% end %>
        <div class="add_requiredskill"><button><%= link_to_add_association 'add a required skill', f, :requiredskills %></button></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

user/_requiredskill_fields.html.erb

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <%= f.association :category_advert, collection: CategoryAdvert.all, prompt: "select a category" %>
  <%= f.grouped_collection_select :category_advertskill_id, CategoryAdvert.order(:name), :category_advertskills, :name, :id, :name, {prompt: "Select a category"}, {class: "category_advertskill"} %>
  <button><%= link_to_remove_association 'remove required skill', f %></button>
</div>
```

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :xml, :json
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @users = User.all
    @user = current_user
  end

  def show
    @resume = @user.resume
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    @user.update(user_params)
    redirect_to @user
  end

  private
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, :firstname, :lastname, :city, :category_qualification_id, :category_careerlevel_id, :desiredjob, :category_distance_id, :preferedlocation, :category_notice_id, :category_country_id, :category_positiontype_id, :image, :cvattachment, :hidecv, :jobadvice, :validlicense, :owntransport, :considerrelocation, :preferredlocation, :neednotice, :stratdate, :availabletowork, :category_outsource_id, :category_advertskill_id, :category_age_id, languages_attributes: [:id, :name, :_destroy], requiredskills_attributes: [:id, :name, :category_advert_id, :category_advertskill_id, :category_year_id, :category_level_id, :_destroy])
    end
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :requiredskills
  has_many :category_advertskills, through: :requiredskills
  has_many :category_adverts, through: :requiredskills

  has_one :resume

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :languages, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :requiredskills, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

Comment: Please show your controller, most likely this has nothing to do with cocoon gem. Also, you have link wrapped within a button - that is very interesting however probably not the best practice. Is clicking on the link adding the fields?

Comment: paste the code for user model also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def edit
  @requiredskills = @user.requiredskills.present? ? @user.requiredskills : @user.requiredskills.build
end
```

change this code in controller